# Which algorithm is the best based on P-Values

Tags: classification, svm, p-value

I used the following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (7, 7))
plt.boxplot([totalP['poly'], totalP['rbf'], totalP['linear'], totalP['gf']])
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 5), kernels)
plt.title('P values for each svm kernel')
plt.xlabel('SVM kernel')
plt.ylabel('P values Rate')
plt.ioff()
plt.savefig('images/pValues.png')
plt.show()
```

**Which one of the algorithms do we consider the best (in t-values and p-values) and why?
Is it the nearest to 1 or the nearest to 0?**

[image]

Comment: Can you add the image as well? It is confusing to try to answer your question otherwise.

Comment: Okay.. i added it now to the original question

Comment: what was the dataset

Comment: It is a kaggle dataset; prostate dataset